Install Android apkm programmatically / cli
Edit: I'm not sure how to pass the list of apks In the current directory into adb install multiple from the article? I tried these:
adb -s localhost:5555 install-multiple --user 0 *.apk 
ls .apk | adb -s localhost:5555 install-multiple --user 0

I have several .apkm files each for different apps that I would like to install at once.
For a normal APK this is easy enough to do looping with adb instead app.apk
When I try: adb install --user 0 app.apkm
I Get this: Performing Streamed Install
adb: filename doesn't end .apk or .apex: apkm.apkm
I found online a way of installing from the extracted apps from the apkm?
Is there a way to install a .apkm file from adb/cli?
I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any suggestions

Your post is inconsistent, often you write .mapk but also .apkm. The latter makes more sense, if this is a type/auto correction problem please edit your question and fix it.

.apkm files are not an official Android app format, thus you can not install it directly via adb. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247728/2241

Ah sorry, I'll correct it to apkm

Thank you for replying, it's a shame you can not install directly. I think the apps I found can only install apkm files 1 at a time and not a list of them

You can write a script (batch, Powershell, bash, ...) on your own, unpack the apkm file to a folder, install all contained apk files as shown in the linked answer in my last comment and then proceed with the next apkm file.

unzip *.apkm adb install-multiple *.apk   If there are multiple apkm files would the install multiple work as they will have different signatures or should I try installing them one by one?

I'm not sure how to pass the list of apks In the current directory into adb install multiple from the article? I tried these:
adb -s localhost:5555 install-multiple --user 0 *.apk 
ls .apk | adb -s localhost:5555 install-multiple --user 0


What OS and shell do you use?
